# In PHP is there a built-in function to replace this foreach loop?

Tags: php, arrays, loops

In order to integrate icons into the navbar I use key=>value arrays to store a file name with an icon tag. In the navbar I use a foreach loop to build dropdown menus or index into an array for an individual navlink. This also allows to dynamically build and alter the dropdown menus very easily.

```
$homepage = array(
  'index.php'=>'<i class="fa fa-home"></i>'
);
$guestpages = array(
  'createaccount.php'=>'<i class="fa fa-university"></i>',
  'login.php'=>'<i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i>'
);
$logout = array(
  'logout.php'=>'<i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i>'
);
$pages = array($homepage,$guestpages,$logout);
```

I also parse the URL to determine what page the client is viewing.

```
$pagename = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```

And in order to associate the parsed URL with the appropriate icon tag from the $pages array, I currently use a nested foreach loop:

```
foreach ($pages as $pagearray) {
  foreach ($pagearray as $page => $icon) {
    if($pagename == $page) {
      $pageicon = $icon;
    }
  }
}
```

And what I'd like to do instead is something like this:

```
$pageicon = $pages[?][$pagename];
```

Does a similar alternative solution exist?

Comment: Why the three separate arrays? If you'd just have `$pages = ['index.php' => ...]`, you could simply do `$pages[basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])]`…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your pagename must be unique, you can build your array in a single dimension, like this:

```
$pages = [
    'index.php'=>'<i class="fa fa-home"></i>',
    'createaccount.php'=>'<i class="fa fa-university"></i>',
    'login.php'=>'<i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i>',
    'logout.php'=>'<i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i>',
];
```

Then just use:

```
$icon = $pages[basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])] ?? '<some default>';
```

[Edit] Alternatively, you can use `array_merge()` to combine your arrays:

```
$pages = array_merge($homepage, $guestpages, $logout);
```

Comment: This would complicate the navbar construction though, because index.php and logout.php are individual links while createaccount.php and login.php are both in the same dropdown menu. So on the navbar I use a loop: foreach($guestpages as...) to build the dropdown menu containing the links to createaccount.php and login.php. I wouldn't be able to create individual dropdown menus from the $pages array, and don't want to maintain a seperate $pages array that is not nested.

Comment: Then just use `array_merge()` to combine them.